# WPF Binding not working on nested listview

Tags: wpf, data-binding, catel

I have a treeview with a dropdown button.  The dropdownbutton displays options for adding nodes to the tree.  When the user selects an option I want a command to be fired off and handled by a command in the parent user control.  FYI using catel MVVM framework.

XAML

```html
<Grid Margin="10">
  <TreeView x:Name="CriteriaTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Criteria}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
        <catel:EventToCommand Command="{Binding NodeSelectionChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=CriteriaTreeView, Path=SelectedItem}" DisableAssociatedObjectOnCannotExecute="False" />
      </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <TreeView.Resources>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:Group}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding OperatorOptions}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedOperator}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayText" SelectedValuePath="Value" />
        </StackPanel>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:Leaf}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <TextBlock Text="Where Account Number " />
          <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding OperatorOptions}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedOperator}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayText" SelectedValuePath="Value" />
          <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" Width="50" />
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:NodeFactory}">
        <xctk:DropDownButton Content="Add Condition" IsOpen="{Binding IsOpen}">
          <xctk:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AddOptions}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedOption}">
              <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                  <catel:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference ManageSyncControl}, Path=DataContext.AddNode}" DisableAssociatedObjectOnCannotExecute="False" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
              </i:Interaction.Triggers>
              <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <WrapPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}" />
                  </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
              </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
          </xctk:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
        </xctk:DropDownButton>
      </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
  </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

VIEWMODEL

```js
    public class ManageSyncedAccountsViewModel: ViewModelEventBase {
      public ManageSyncedAccountsViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator): base(eventAggregator) {
        AddNode = new Command(OnAddNode);
        NodeSelectionChanged = new Command < Node > (OnNodeSelectionChanged);

        var root = new Group("Root");
        var g1 = new Group("Group 1");
        g1.AddNode(new Leaf("Leaf 1"));
        g1.AddNode(new Leaf("Leaf 2"));
        var g2 = new Group("Group2");
        g2.AddNode(new Leaf("Leaf 3"));
        g2.AddNode(new Leaf("Leaf 4"));
        root.AddNode(g1);
        root.AddNode(g2);
        root.AddNode(new Leaf("Leaf 5"));

        Criteria = new List < Group > {
          root
        };
      }

      private void OnNodeSelectionChanged(Node target) {
        SelectedNode = target;
      }

      private void OnAddNode() {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("WOOHOO");
      }

      public List < Group > Criteria {
        get {
          return GetValue < List < Group >> (CriteriaProperty);
        }
        set {
          SetValue(CriteriaProperty, value);
        }
      }

      public static readonly PropertyData CriteriaProperty = RegisterProperty(nameof(Criteria), typeof(List < Group > ));


      public Node SelectedNode {
        get {
          return GetValue < Node > (SelectedNodeProperty);
        }
        set {
          SetValue(SelectedNodeProperty, value);
        }
      }

      public static readonly PropertyData SelectedNodeProperty = RegisterProperty(nameof(SelectedNode), typeof(Node));

      public Command AddNode {
        get;
        private set;
      }
      public Command < Node > NodeSelectionChanged {
        get;
        private set;
      }
    }
```

When I run this I get a binding error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'AddNode' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindowViewModel'
>   (HashCode=-1718218621)'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.AddNode;
>   DataItem='ManageSyncedAccountsView' (Name='ManageSyncControl'); target
>   element is 'EventToCommand' (HashCode=6678752); target property is
>   'Command' (type 'ICommand')

I tried using relative source searching for ancestor type and element name, but both of those options returned even more confusing error messages.  Clearly I'm missing something here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message in your question, the Button's DataContext is of type `MainWindowViewModel`, but the class which owns the `AddNode` command is called `ManageSyncedAccountsViewModel`.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'AddNode' property not found on 'object' ''**MainWindowViewModel**' (HashCode=-1718218621)'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.AddNode; DataItem='ManageSyncedAccountsView' (Name='ManageSyncControl'); target element is 'EventToCommand' (HashCode=6678752); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Try putting `AddNode` on `MainWindowViewModel` where the button can see it.

Comment: And the "staring at the problem too long and not reading carefully" issue strikes again.  Many thanks Ed, brain was stuck ignoring the part in bold!